# Single game probability or cumulative probability

Tags: statistics, probability, probability-theory

My friends and I were playing a card game the other night. The game requires each of us to guess whether another is holding a specific card. There are three card possibilities: A, B, and C. There were three rounds. My friend had Card A two rounds in a row. On the third round, we were debating whether he had Card A again.

**Option 1**: In this round, there is a 1/3 chance that he has Card A.

**Option 2**: Given that he has received Card A twice in a row, the chance that he will receive it again is unlikely (1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3) = 1/27.

In the absence of any other information, is Option 2 a valid heuristic to guess whether he has Card A? What statistical concept/probabilistic concept does this address? Independence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

As any round in your game is completely independent of the others, you shuffle the cards again, they look all the same, the chance of receiving this specific card in each game is 1/3 for each player. 
Option 2 describes how probable the series of receiving the same card 3 time in a row is within all possible combinations. Note however that any other specific order combination e.g. A,B,C has exactly the same probability. Only when you stop caring about the order and consider A,C,B the same as B,A,C then receiving as three kinds of cards without caring in which order they occur becomes more probable.

Comment: So to clarify, in that setting, you would say it's a 1/3 chance rather than a 1/27 chance, even though drawing three in a row is unlikely?

Comment: For the next game, his chance of drawing cars A is again 1/3 as there are only 3 cards available.

Comment: So is it possible to reconcile these points? To simultaneously play knowing that it there is ~3% chance it happened 3 times in a row but also know that for a given round there is a 1/3 chance he has Card A?

Comment: This is a counter-intuitive idea in probability. Even though the chance of having such a strait decreases with every additional game, within the game itself the chance of drawing this card with probability 1/3 remains. For the same reason analyses of which Lotto numbers have been drawn how many times before are not helpful as each game is independent of the ones before. The law of large numbers will only truly take care of 'equality' for infinitely many game which none of us will ever play.